# Splitting the rows that has "|" using separate() fn not splitted

Tags: r, tidyr

my data looks like

```
> company
                          name                             category_list
11                     1-4 All              Entertainment|Games|Software
12            1.618 Technology        Networking|Real Estate|Web Hosting
13               1-800-DENTIST                       Health and Wellness
14               1-800-DOCTORS                       Health and Wellness
15 1-800-PublicRelations, Inc. Internet Marketing|Media|Public Relations
```

i will have to split the category_list column based the values. when the values are pipe separated, the row should be split.

i tried the same using separate function but the column is not populated with any values

```
c1 <- company %>% separate(category_list,into=c("primary_Sector"), sep="|")
```

Actual output:

```
                      name primary_Sector
11                     1-4 All               
12            1.618 Technology               
13               1-800-DENTIST               
14               1-800-DOCTORS               
15 1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.
```

Expected output

```
    name      category_list
11 1-4 All    Entertainment
12 1-4 All    Games
13 1-4 All    Software
```

can someone tell me what is wrong?

Comment: escape the separator. `company %>% separate(category_list,into=c("primary_Sector"), sep="\\|")`

Comment: Why? Because according to the `?separate` docs, `sep` *"is interpreted as a regular expression."* In regex, the pipe `|` symbol has special meaning, so to indicate a literal pipe you need to escape it with the double backslashes. See [`?regex`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/regex.html) for more information on regular expressions, though you don't strictly need to know them if you know how to escape them as RonakShah suggested.

Comment: the newly splitted records are not being displayed now. if there were 15 records already and 5 records are to be added based on the split, there should be 20 now but the df still has 15 records

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`tidyr::separate()` does the column-wise separation, `tidyr::separate_rows()` does the row-wise separation:

```
library(tidyr)

read.table(
  text="name;category_list
1-4 All;Entertainment|Games|Software
1.618 Technology;Networking|Real Estate|Web Hosting
1-800-DENTIST;Health and Wellness
1-800-DOCTORS;Health and Wellness
1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.;Internet Marketing|Media|Public Relations", 
  sep=";", header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE
) %>% 
  separate_rows(category_list, sep = "\\|")
##                           name       category_list
## 1                      1-4 All       Entertainment
## 2                      1-4 All               Games
## 3                      1-4 All            Software
## 4             1.618 Technology          Networking
## 5             1.618 Technology         Real Estate
## 6             1.618 Technology         Web Hosting
## 7                1-800-DENTIST Health and Wellness
## 8                1-800-DOCTORS Health and Wellness
## 9  1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.  Internet Marketing
## 10 1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.               Media
## 11 1-800-PublicRelations, Inc.    Public Relations
```